# Save new values of java object using Py4J

Tags: java, python, py4j

I'm just curious if there is any function in Py4j that enables saving new values in Java object.
I mean, using `get_field` function I can easily get values of java object and with `set_field`, I can change that values, but I guess, only in Python. I cannot see any changes in Java application.

Example:

```
A=get_field(record,"values") 
print (A[0]) 
A[0]=600 
set_field(record,"values",A) 
print(temp[0])
```

Comment: Can you provide a small code example? Calling set_field from Python will change the value of a field on the Java side so it should definitively be observable in the Java application. Maybe you are not referring to the same object though.

Comment: Finally I got my error (really simply and have nothing in common with py4j) I feel a little bit a shame of it. Shortly, your library works ingeniously and thank you for it! :)